# Which event happens when I touch the thumb of the slider?

Tags: uwp, slider, uwp-xaml

I'm customize a slider to making seeking bar for video. What I want is that when I touch the thumb the video stops. Then I can drag the thumb and display the video corresponding to the slider's value. This is my Slider in XAML

```
<Slider Style="{StaticResource SliderStyle1}" Grid.Column="1" x:Name="volumeSlider" 
Width="Auto"  VerticalAlignment="Center" ValueChanged="volumeSlider_ValueChanged" 
DragLeave="volumeSlider_DragLeave" DragEnter="volumeSlider_DragEnter" 
DragStarting="volumeSlider_DragStarting" 
ManipulationStarted="volumeSlider_ManipulationStarted" ManipulationMode="All" 
Tapped="volumeSlider_Tapped"/>
```

[image]

I've try many event but none of them occur when mouse pointer starts touching the thumb (Not tap or click). Does anyone know about such event?

Comment: What would be the difference from a tap/click? Would it mean that the mouse is pressed for a longer time?

Comment: @MartinZikmund That's when I put the mouse pointer on the thumb and started pressing. Tap and click will only execute when I have already pressed and release the mouse button

Answer (score 2):

You would normally use `PointerPressed` event (see [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.uielement.pointerpressed?view=winrt-19041)). However, this has two issues. First, the `Thumb` already handles such pointer interaction, so `PointerPressed` never bubbles out of the `Slider`. Secondly, it would be triggered for any location of the `Slider`, not only the thumb.

To work around this, you will need to handle the event on the `Thumb` itself. First, we will create a helper method that searches the visual tree:

```
public T FindChild<T>(DependencyObject parent)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(parent); i++)
    {
        var child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(parent, i);
        if (child is T typedChild)
        {
            return typedChild;
        }
        var inner = FindChild<T>(child);
        if (inner != null)
        {
            return inner;
        }
    }
    return default;
}
```

Note that this and many similar useful methods are available in the Windows Community Toolkit as part of [Visual Tree Extensions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communitytoolkit/extensions/visualtree).

Now, we search for the `Thumb` within the control:

```
var thumb = FindChild<Thumb>(MySlider);
```

Finally, we attach the `PointerPressed` event. Because it is already handled by the `Slider` control itself, we need to use `AddHandler`, that allows us to observe event that are marked as handled too:

```
thumb.AddHandler(
    UIElement.PointerPressedEvent, 
    new PointerEventHandler(Thumb_PointerPressed), 
    true);
```

And in the handler you can then do anything you require:

```
private void Thumb_PointerPressed(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // ...
}
```

Comment: If I find thumb right after calling InitializeComponent function then MySlider won't have any children. So I have to call the FindChild function on PageLoaded. Why is that?

Comment: The reason is that in that particular moment the `Slider's` template was not yet applied, so the child does not exist yet. You can also execute it in `Slider.Loaded` or derive from `Slider` and override `OnApplyTemplate`.

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, you want an event to have occurred when the mouse pointer starts touching the thumb. [PointerEntered](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.uielement.pointerentered?view=winrt-19041) event occurs when a pointer enters the hit test area of this element, which meets your requirement.

**Update:**

Derive from official document, mouse input is associated with a single pointer assigned when mouse input is first detected. Clicking a mouse button (left, wheel, or right) creates a secondary association between the pointer and that button through the [PointerPressed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.uielement.pointerpressed?view=winrt-19041) event. The [PointerReleased](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.uielement.pointerreleased?view=winrt-19041) event is fired only when that same mouse button is released.
Because of this exclusive association, other mouse button clicks are routed through the PointerMoved event. So you can find the Thumb control named “`HorizontalThumb`”, and add [PointerMoved](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.uielement.pointermoved?view=winrt-19041) event like following.

```
private async void HorizontalThumb_PointerMoved(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Windows.UI.Xaml.Input.Pointer ptr = e.Pointer;
    if (ptr.PointerDeviceType == Windows.Devices.Input.PointerDeviceType.Mouse)
    {
        Windows.UI.Input.PointerPoint ptrPt = e.GetCurrentPoint(MySlider);
        if (ptrPt.Properties.IsLeftButtonPressed)
        {
          //add your code to stop video                 
        }
    }
    e.Handled = true;
}
```

Comment: Sorry if my description makes you misunderstood. I think `PointerEntered` is when the pointer starts hovering the `Slider`. But I mean when the pointer starts to touch the thumb (when press down mouse on thumb)

Comment: You can do this by changing your `SliderStyle1`. Please find the `Thumb` control named `HorizontalThumb` in your style, and add `Tapped` event.

Comment: When I set it like that, Tapped only fires when the mouse cursor pressed and lift up. Beside, PointerPressed event isn't working when set in XAML.

Comment: I have updated the previous answer, you could check if it will meet your requirements.