# Measuring the width of a control that is not actually part of the UI layout in UWP

Tags: c#, uwp, combobox, width

I am trying to create a UWP control that is a combobox but whose width stays constant no matter which item is selected. (The default ComboBox will resize itself every time a new item is picked, which may cause the layout of the rest of the page to change.)

I am basing my control off of one that I wrote for WPF, which works fine. This is the code for the UWP version:

```
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Windows.Foundation;
using System.Reflection;

namespace Foo
{
    public sealed class ConstantWidthComboBox : ComboBox
    {
        private readonly double _emptyWidth;

        public ConstantWidthComboBox()
        {
            this.Measure(new Size(double.PositiveInfinity, double.PositiveInfinity));
            _emptyWidth = this.DesiredSize.Width;
        }

        protected override void OnItemsChanged(object e)
        {
            base.OnItemsChanged(e);
            AdjustWidth();
        }

        private void AdjustWidth()
        {
            double maxItemWidth = 0;

            foreach (var item in Items)
            {
                if (item is ComboBoxItem cmbItem)
                {
                    cmbItem.Measure(new Size(double.PositiveInfinity, double.PositiveInfinity));
                    if (cmbItem.DesiredSize.Width > maxItemWidth)
                        maxItemWidth = cmbItem.DesiredSize.Width;
                }
                else
                {
                    object content = item;
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.DisplayMemberPath))
                    {
                        content = EvaluateDisplayMemberPath(item, this.DisplayMemberPath);
                    }

                    ContentPresenter presenter = new ContentPresenter() { Content = content };
                    presenter.Measure(new Size(double.PositiveInfinity, double.PositiveInfinity));
                    if (presenter.DesiredSize.Width > maxItemWidth)
                        maxItemWidth = presenter.DesiredSize.Width;
                }
            }
            this.Width = maxItemWidth + _emptyWidth + this.Padding.Left + this.Padding.Right;
        }

        private object EvaluateDisplayMemberPath(object item, string path)
        {
            if (item == null)
                return null;

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(path))
                return item;

            int k = path.IndexOf(".");
            string property = (k == -1) ? path : path.Substring(0, k);
            string trailer = (k == -1) ? null : path.Substring(k + 1);

            object value = item.GetType().GetProperty(property, BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance).GetValue(item, null);

            return EvaluateDisplayMemberPath(value, trailer);
        }
    }
}
```

(Note that this works if the combobox consists of ComboBoxItems or if the DisplayMemberPath is used to get the text to display. I haven't tested it on wider circumstances such as if the items are data templates or whatnot.)

While this works in WPF, in UWP the presenter's `DesiredSize.Width` value is always zero.

Does anyone know how to measure the (hypothetical) width of a control that is not actually part of the UI layout in UWP, such as for the ContentPresenter in the above code?

Answer (score 0):

Please find the `ContentPresenter` control through [Visual Tree](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communitytoolkit/extensions/visualtree), then access the `ActualWidth` property.

You can follow the first answer of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65589191/which-event-happens-when-i-touch-the-thumb-of-the-slider) edited by *Martin Zikmund* to do this like following.

```
private void Page_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
var contentPresenter = FindChild<ContentPresenter>(MyConstantWidthComboBox);
        double k = contentPresenter.ActualWidth;
}

public T FindChild<T>(DependencyObject parent)
{
 for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(parent); i++)
 {
    var child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(parent, i);
    if (child is T typedChild)
    {
        return typedChild;
    }
    var inner = FindChild<T>(child);
    if (inner != null)
    {
        return inner;
    }
 }
return default;
}
```